# Set custom EntryPoint for a simple application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, configuration, entry-point

I have this simple hello world c++ application:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test()
{
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
}
```

I want to use `test` as my custom entry point. So far I tried to set `Linker -> Advanced -> Entrypoint` to `test` But I got lots of lnk2001 errors. Is it possible to somehow remove any main() wmain() WinMain() and use my function with just Visual studio settings?

Comment: If you want to use custom entry point then you need to either stop using standard library facilities or provide CRT startup routines.

Comment: What is `Linker -> Advanced -> Entrypoint`?

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland This is in Project Properties. Right-click on your project and select Propertes then ...

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland Note that there is [tag:visual-studio] tag

Comment: @user7860670 I tried to change my code to C like: `#include <cstdio>
void test()
{
 printf("Hello\n");
}` but millions of E0147 and E0020 error occured

Comment: `printf` is a part of CRT and still requires all that runtime stuff that is usually getting into executable.

Comment: The best option is to simply use the standard CRT normally, and let `main()` call `test()`, eg: `int main() { test(); }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redifining C/C++ entry point in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044353/redifining-c-c-entry-point-in-microsoft-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT That question is similar, indeed, but the (only) answer is unsatisfactory. As pointed out in Hans Passant's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044353/redifining-c-c-entry-point-in-microsoft-visual-studio-2015#comment67368272_40045581), linking the CRT while bypassing the CRT initialization is downright dangerous. My answer here is more limited in scope (no CRT, period) but it's essentially safe. Linking the CRT *and* properly initializing it would also be technically possible, though a lot more laborious and would have to rely on CRT implementation internals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a custom entry point in a Windows app bypasses the entire CRT startup and global C++ initializations. Because of that, it requires not using the CRT, and turning off compiler features that depend on the CRT such as [`/GS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gs-buffer-security-check?view=msvc-160) buffer checks and other [`/RTC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/rtc-run-time-error-checks?view=msvc-160) run-time error checks.

The following is an example of a minimal app with the custom entry point `test`.

```
#include <sdkDdkVer.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

// compile with /GS- lest
// LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
//#pragma strict_gs_check(off)

// turn off /RTC*
#pragma runtime_checks("", off)

#pragma comment(linker, "/nodefaultlib /subsystem:windows /ENTRY:test")

int __stdcall test(void)
{
    OutputDebugStringA("custom /entry:test\n");

    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

More insight can be found in Raymond Chen's [WinMain is just the conventional name for the Win32 process entry point](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=10573).

Comment: Wonderful. It actually worked. Thank u for the sample code.