# "error LNK2005: already defined in .obj" for inline definition

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-errors, inline

I'm on Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.6.6. I created a Visual C++ Empty Project and added the following:

Foo.h:

```
#pragma once
struct Foo
{
    static Foo F1;
};
inline Foo Foo::F1;
```

Bar.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"
```

Baz.cpp: (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65078857/1715765)

```
#include <sdkDdkVer.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#pragma runtime_checks("", off)
#pragma comment(linker, "/nodefaultlib /subsystem:windows /ENTRY:test")
int __stdcall test(void) { ExitProcess(0); }

#include "Foo.h"
```

I get the following when compiling. It compiles fine if I remove one `#include "Foo.h"`

```
Baz.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static struct Foo Foo::F1" (?F1@Foo@@2U1@A) already defined in Bar.obj
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I'll bet you could remove almost all of this code and still show the problem. Don't make people wade through all that Windows stuff if it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: @PeteBecker There needs to be an entry point.

Comment: @H.v.M. -- are you sure that this **only** happens when you have all that Windows cruft? That seems unlikely. Try a simple project that's a normal C++ application. You'll reach a much broader audience.

Comment: @PeteBecker I don't know how to make the example smaller. If I remove everything except `#include "Foo.h"`, it doesn't compile because there needs to be an entry point.

Comment: @H.v.M. -- okay, you have some setting somewhere that says you're building a Windows application. If you don't know where to find that you can't fix it, of course. But Microsoft's stuff is capable of building ordinary applications where you don't need all that noise.

Comment: @HansPassant "_The inline modifier is not sensible on variable declarations._": It is since C++17.

Comment: VS2017 project default to C++14.  I think, been a while.

Comment: @HansPassant Mine is on C++17. You get a different error when you try to use inline that way in C++14.

Comment: [Depends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170).  Use Help > About to see the version number, run the VS Installer to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a compiler bug or non-conformance to me.

If I ignore all of the Windows/MSVC-specific stuff in the example, then that's a valid standard C++ program (except for missing `main`).